# POST params in ROR inaccessible but visible in console

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am posting up some data to my ROR app using a jquery ajax call

I've stripped this part down to being hard coded so I can get it to work

```
var testjson = '{"company": {"name": "acme", "address": "123 carrot street"}}';

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "JSON",
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/home/scoring/' + 1234 + "/update",
      data: datas,
      success: function(){
        alert('success');
      }
    });
```

When it hits the correct controller I can get access to the querystrings "1234" which is called match_id (within the route file)

```
  match "home/scoring/:match_id/update" => "home#update"
```

But I am unable to access the POST elements, my root element "company" should be accessible as params[:company] but it simply returns a nil

Looking at the Console I can see the data getting passed up

> Started POST "/home/scoring/1365750000348629332744/update" for
>   127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-11 00:43:45 +0100 Processing by HomeController#update as JSON   Parameters: {"{\"company\": {\"name\":
>   \"acme\", \"address\": \"123 carrot street\"}}"=>nil,
>   "match_id"=>"136575000034 8629332744"}

although the "=>nil" is a little worrying (why is it nil?) I am unable to find why I this is causing me such a issue.

Comment: Does a lower-case `"json"` for `dataType` fix it? Not sure if it's case-sensitive. But it looks like it's taking the data not as JSON, but as the form element. try using a normal JSON object, too, not a string.

Answer (score 3):

You're passing an already encoded string to jQuery, which is then encoding it again.

You need to just store the data as an actual JavaScript hash, not a string...

```
var testjson = {"company": {"name": "acme", "address": "123 carrot street"}};
```

... and jQuery will handle encoding it as JSON for you. As it stands, your `params` contain a single key, and that key is the string `"{"company": {"name": "acme", "address": "123 carrot street"}}"`, which maps to the value of `nil`.